# Why my Google earth exported KMZ file is not a XML file but a binary one?

Tags: google-earth

According to wikipedia, kmz is a:

> DescriptionKeyhole Markup Language is an XML notation for expressing geographic annotation and visualization within Internet-based, two-dimensional maps and three-dimensional Earth browsers. KML was developed for use with Google Earth, which was originally named Keyhole Earth Viewer.

However, the KMZ file got exported by Google Earth is not a XML one. It's even not a XML file but a binary file.

How can I see the XML content?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [KMZ is a zip file which contains a KML document](https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/learn/packaging-content-in-a-kmz-file/#what_is_a_kmz_file), you can use an application like 7-Zip to open it and extract the KML.